# Split string at first alphabetic character

Tags: c#, string

I have a following string array as shown in the image.  while looping through the array, i need to separate  numeric value and Alphabetic value . 
 eg:

- 35.00MY to  35.00  and MY
- 2.10D8 to 2.10 and D8
- 80.00YRI to 80.00 and YRI
- 4.00G8 to 4.00 and  G8

  I tried following code , but that didn't help

```cs
foreach (string taxText in taxSplit) {
    Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
    Match result = re.Match(taxText);
    string alphaPart = result.Groups[1].ToString();
    string numberPart = result.Groups[2].ToString(); }
```

[image]

Both returned  empty

[image]

Comment: what happen if its 35.00ab3500bc

Comment: i  need that as 35.00  and ab3500bc.    I will always have  number at start and then an alphabet with or without number

Comment: Your regex doesn't come close to what you've described. Your numbers and letters are reversed; your samples are NumberLetter, while your regex is LetterNumber. Try `([)(0-9\.]+)(.+)`; the numbers are in Groups[1], the letters in Groups[2]. Works with all of the samples you posted. The third will include a blank space before `G8`, but you can remove that with `String.Trim()` if that's an issue.

Comment: What is representation of D8, YRI ... ?

Comment: @KenWhite,   edited the space in  last one. was a mistake on copy paste

Comment: @makdu are the number always formatted with 2 digits decimals?

Comment: @Xiaoy312, no , that is based on currency. it can be 2  , 3 or 4

Comment: @KenWhite .. got exception  on the following     Regex re = new Regex(@"[)(0-9\.]+)(.+)");

Comment: @KenWhite, After posting , i found that :) extra '[)'

Comment: My fault. Crappy laptop touchpad moved the cursor; I must have bumped it with my palm. Try `([0-9\.]+)(.+)` instead.

Comment: @KenWhite, that worked the way i wanted. Thank you . Doing more testing . but  future looks good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bastardize a `Split` and use a lookahead `(?= ... )` and a lookbehind `(?<= ... )`:

```
string original = "35.00ab3500bc";
Regex reg = new Regex("(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])");
string[] parts = reg.Split(original, 2);
```

Here, we have to instantiate a new `Regex` instance because this version of `Split` isn't available as a `static` method. The pattern we pass says to find a void where the left side of the void is a number (i.e. the lookbehind), and the right side of the void is a letter (i.e. the lookahead). We pass a `2` to say that we want at most two items in `parts`.

Comment: 80.00YRI  returned  three string   ;  - 80.00, - Y , -RI ,

Comment: OK, then I've removed the original pattern. The 2nd pattern I added in recent edits should work for the problem at hand. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lst = new List<string>() { "35.00MY", "2.10D8", "80.00YRI", "4.00GB" };
var res = new List<string>();

lst.ForEach(v =>
{
    res.Add(new string(v.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray()));
    res.Add(v.TrimStart("01234567890.".ToCharArray()));
} );
```